# Cast dict to defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict, python-collections

The following code uses the {} operator to combine two defaultdicts.

```
from collections import defaultdict
aa=defaultdict(str)
bb=defaultdict(str)
aa['foo']+= '1'
bb['bar']+= '2'
cc = {**aa,**bb}
type(cc)
```

But, as we see if we run this, the `{}` operator returns a `dict` type not a `defaultdict` type.

Is there a way to cast a `dict` back to a defaultdict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use unpacking directly in a call to [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).  `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, and will pass those arguments to its parent to create a dictionary as though they had been passed to `dict`.

```
cc = defaultdict(str, **aa, **bb)
# defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {'bar': '2', 'foo': '1'})
```

Comment: This nails it.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the best one-line solution. But note that unpacking makes it inefficient and inputs are over-specified, i.e. requires an input [`defaultdict` type] which shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the long way. The benefit of this method is you don't need to re-specify the type of `defaultdict`:

```
def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    z = x.copy()
    z.update(y)
    return z

cc = merge_two_dicts(aa, bb)
```

Unpacking in a single expression works but is inefficient:

```
n = 500000

d1 = defaultdict(int)
d1.update({i: i for i in range(n)})
d2 = defaultdict(int)
d2.update({i+n:i+n for i in range(n)})

%timeit defaultdict(int, {**d1, **d2})  # 150 ms per loop
%timeit merge_two_dicts(d1, d2)         # 90.9 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultdict` constructor can take two arguments, where the first is the function to use for the default, and the second a mapping (dict). It copies the keys/values from the dict passed in.

```
 >>> d = defaultdict(list, {'a': [1,2,3]})
 >>> d['a']
 [1, 2, 3]
```